# Markers Appearing at Random Times

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to create a map with 3 different markers, but currently each is appearing at a random time.  I think it is a problem with asynchricity.

The test url is here and the map shows up towards the bottom of the page:
http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_carpool.php?hike_id=125

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What's wrong with the markers display? They all pop up at the same time for me. I see the smiley face, red marker, and blue car. I'm running Firefox 3.6.13

Comment: Ditto to what Rachel said - they seem fine in Chrome on Mac. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean you see your markers drawing at different time, e.g. at the beginning you see red one, then yellow, and then blue one. Next time you load the page you could notice blue marker showing first, then yellow and then red one. Do I get your question right? If yes, then do not care about :) It depends on network connection, server loading etc. E.g. look at Net tab of FireBug, first time I got:

[image]

so browser started requesting smile.gif and car.jpg at the same time, after a while marker_sprite was requested. Actually you see that maps.google.com served request faster (though request started later). Then your server (comehike.com) processed request for car.jpg (though it is big one, 1.3kb), and then comes smile.gif (though its size is just 174b and it was first requested image).

Next time I pressed F5 and got images from browser cache, but browser sends some requests to see if they really were not changed:

[image]

notice, that browser started requesting information about car.jpg quite early, but due to connection time, and waiting for result it took a lot to get it (though it is cached, so browsers just waits for confirmation). Again maps.google.com processed request faster than comehike.com.

So this is not about ajax, it depends on when browser will request image, and how fast server will process it (and it depends on its queue etc...).

If you want all markers to be shown at the same time, you need to use CSS Sprites and combine all marker images into the one. Have a look there (any article is good):

1. [CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why
   They’re Cool, and How To Use
   Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
2. [CSS Sprites: Image Slicing’s Kiss
   of Death](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)
3. [The Mystery Of CSS Sprites:
   Techniques, Tools And Tutorials](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)

this way you will have one image instead of three, so when it is loaded browser will display all markers (at least you won't notice that there is any delay between marker drawing). Hope it explains and helps.